# Reversing byte order of a word array using stream operator

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have an array of 32bit words:

```
bit [7:0] byte_array[];
bit [31:0] reg_array[];

reg_array[0] = 32'h01020304;
reg_array[1] = 32'h05060708;
reg_array[2] = 32'h090a0b0c;
```

I want to pack it into an array of bytes with the least significant byte of the word first:

```
byte_aray[0]=0x4
byte_aray[1]=0x3
byte_aray[2]=0x2
byte_aray[3]=0x1
byte_aray[4]=0x8
byte_aray[5]=0x7
byte_aray[6]=0x6
byte_aray[7]=0x5
byte_aray[8]=0xc
byte_aray[9]=0xb
byte_aray[10]=0xa
byte_aray[11]=0x9
```

Is there a way I can do this using purely streaming operator alone? The best I can do without it is this:

```
byte_array={<<32{reg_array}};
byte_array.reverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 byte_array = {<<8{ {<<32{reg_array}} }};
```

Comment: thanks dave that indeed works, I think I tried {<<8{<<32{reg_array}}} and got a expect left brace error before..... can you explain the reason why we need 1 more set of brace {} around {<<32{reg_array}}?   Thanks.

Comment: I have nested a streaming operator inside another streaming operator(note where I have placed the whitespaces). Each streaming operator requires two pairs of braces.